# What encoding to use with raw bytes in a NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, ascii, nsdata

I need to store some raw bytes from `NSData` object into an `NSString` (basically a null encoding) but I am not sure how to do this. Obviously assigning an improper 8-bit encoding would be bad. `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is not OK because the docs say "Strict 7-bit ASCII encoding within 8-bit chars; ASCII values 0…127 only." but I need full range of 0x0 - 0xFF.

`Base64` encoding is NOT an acceptable solution.

Comment: It might help to know a bit more context. Where did the data come from? Where are you trying to send it as a string?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you don't.

An `NSString` is for strings of validly encoded string data;  typically UTF8 or UTF16.  `NSData` is for arbitrary binary data.

If you want to store raw bytes into an `NSString`, you need to encode them and `base64` is one of the most common means of doing so.

Comment: So it means that we have to do base64 encode and decode the NSData and covert the resultant NSData to Nsstring. Am i right?

Comment: Yup -- that'd work.  Generally to be avoided unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1497293-string_encodings/nsnextstepstringencoding):

> 8-bit ASCII encoding with NEXTSTEP extensions.

It appears in the current documentation (as of writing this post) and is available in both Apple and GNU's implementation of the (OPENSTEP) standard.

Caveat: It doesn't state what exactly those "extensions" are, so tread lightly.